# AVL Tree Rotation's

Tags: tree, avl-tree

Just a quick question about avl trees. 
If I had this tree:

```
    27
   /  \
  9    50
 / \
2   15
      \
       21
```

Why does it balance to this answer?:

```
    15
   /  \
  9    27
 /    /  \
2    21   50
```

Instead of this (or are they both valid?):

```
    21
   /  \
  15   27
 /  \    \
2    9    50
```

Comment: Did you accidentally swap the 9 and 15 in the second one? Because as it is that is not a valid search tree. It is still balanced though.

Answer (score 3):

According to the retracing algorithm for AVL tree the balancing is done in two steps:

I. `left rotation` is done for the left sub-tree:

```
  |              |
  9              15
 / \            /  \
2   15   =>    9    21
     \        /
      21     2
```

II. `right rotation` is done for the whole tree:

```
      27           15
     /  \         /  \
    15   50 =>   9    27
   /  \         /    /  \
  9    21      2    21   50
 /
2
```

The second answer is simply incorrect as it didn't preserve order of elements.